# void no puede ser convertido a int

Tags: java, poo

En el metodo precioFinal() intento que del que sea X caso me regrese el resultado de la suma del preciof

Codigo:

```
public class Electrodomestico{
public int preciobase;
public String color;
public char consumo;
public int peso;

public Electrodomestico(){
this.preciobase = 1000;
this.color = "blanco";
this.consumo = 'F'; 
this.peso = 5;
}

public Electrodomestico(int preciobase, int peso){
this.preciobase = preciobase; //$1000
this.color = "blanco"; 
this.consumo = 'F'; 
this.peso = peso; // 5 kg
}

public Electrodomestico(int preciobase, String color, char consumo, int peso){
this.preciobase = preciobase; //$1000
this.color = color; //blanco
this.consumo = consumo; //F
this.peso = peso; // 5kg
}

//Metodos
public void comprobarConsumoEnergetico(char letra){
    switch(letra){
        case 'A':
        System.out.println("A");
        break;

        case 'B' :
        System.out.println("B");
        break;

        case 'C' :
        System.out.println("C");
        break;

        case 'D' :
        System.out.println("D");
        break;

        case 'E' : 
        System.out.println("E");
        break;

        case 'F' :
        System.out.println("F");
        break;

        default:
        System.out.println("F");
    }
}

public void comprobarColor(String color){

    switch(color){
        case "blanco":
        System.out.println("");
        break;
        case "negro":
        System.out.println("");
        break;
        case "rojo":
        System.out.println("");
        break;
        case "azul":
        System.out.println("");
        break;
        case "gris":
        System.out.println("");
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("blanco");
    }
}

public int precioFinal(){
    int pesof; 
    if ((getPeso() >= 0) && (getPeso() <= 19)) {
       pesof = System.out.println(getPreciobase() + 100);
    }else if((getPeso() >= 20) && (getPeso() <= 49)) {
       pesof = System.out.println(getPreciobase() + 500);
    }else if ((getPeso() >= 50) && (getPeso() <= 79)) {
       pesof = System.out.println(getPreciobase() + 800);
    }else if (getPeso() > 80) {
       pesof = System.out.println(getPreciobase() + 1000);
    }
    return pesof;
 //System.out.println(comprobarConsumoEnergetico(getConsumo()));
 System.out.println(getPeso());
 System.out.println(getPreciobase());
}

//Getters y Setters
public void setPreciobase(int preciobase){
    this.preciobase = preciobase;
}
public int getPreciobase(){
    return preciobase;
}
public void setColor(String color){
    this.color = color;
}
public String getColor(){
    return color;
}
public void setConsumo(char consumo){
    this.consumo = consumo;
}
public char getConsumo(){
    return consumo;
}
public void setPeso(int peso){
    this.peso = peso;
}
public int getPeso(){
    return peso;
}
```

}

Error:

```
    .\Electrodomestico.java:86: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int
           pesof = System.out.println(getPreciobase() + 100);
                                     ^
.\Electrodomestico.java:88: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int
           pesof = System.out.println(getPreciobase() + 500);
                                     ^
.\Electrodomestico.java:90: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int
           pesof = System.out.println(getPreciobase() + 800);
                                     ^
.\Electrodomestico.java:92: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int
           pesof = System.out.println(getPreciobase() + 1000);
                                     ^
4 errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bienvenido iTzprodigui, bueno... el error te sale porque simplemente estas haciendo la asignación a la variable pesof con una impresión en pantalla.

la variable pesof esta declarada al principio de la clase Electrodomestico como tipo entero:

```
public int preciobase;
```

y la impresión:

```
System.out.println(getPreciobase() + 100)
```

aunque muestre por la consola un resultado, ese metodo no devuelve nada (**void**), y solo ejecuta las instrucciones que tiene dentro.

ahora si te fijas tu código:

```
pesof = System.out.println(getPreciobase() + 100);
```

a una variable de tipo entero le estas asignando un vació (**void**)...

Lo que deberías hacer para que ya no te salga el error seria dejar las instrucciones así:

```
pesof = getPreciobase() + 100;
```

sin el System.out.println().

Espero te haya ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Por cierto aportando con otro detalle: coloca los **System.out.println** pon encima del **return** de la función y no por debajo.

```
System.out.println(getPeso());
System.out.println(getPreciobase());
return pesof;
}
```

Comment: Por qué? Siempre considera dar un argumento para dar más peso a tu respuesta